# "undefined" is not valid JSON Error while trying to preview data in Azure Data Factory Data Flow

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, google-cloud-dataflow

I have couple of JSON files in Azure data lake, I have used Data Flows in ADF to transform the JSON files and load them into Azure SQL, I have done this operation 100s of times before but since yesterday I am getting an error "undefined" is not valid JSON while trying to preview the same files in ADF. The error does not have any more description. It is really frustrating I have made sure the file path and everything is correct but I don't know what I am doing wrong.[image]

Comment: Can you add your sample of JSON and source options of the dataflow?

Comment: My json has key : value pair with list as values. I noticed that when I import schema from the dataset the imported schema does not recognize the key value pairs inside of the values lists but the preview data works in the dataflow. But when I import schema from the dataflow it recognizes the key value pairs inside of the json list but gives out the error above. I don’t think this is an error caused by permissions. I can’t share the json file as it contains sensitive information.

Comment: Can you share the JSON structure with any sample data?